# SetEnvIfNoCase redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi all ive been learning wildcard methods using  `SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent` and wildcards,
But using the example below.only serves a 403 error page if a useragent matches the wildcards.
but what i want is to redirect the "user-agent" to another website such as a black hole or spam page.
using something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://send junk to here/`

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent "(B2|Bac|Bad|Bag|Bai|Bast|Batch|Bing|Bite|Bla|Blex)" bad_bot=yes
#
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

what can i replace the  `Deny from env=bad_bot` with to make it  redirect to the wanted website instead of serving the 403 error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rewrite rule like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} B2|Bac|Bad|Bag|Bai|Bast|Batch|Bing|Bite|Bla|Blex [NC]
RewriteRule  !^spam/ http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

**UPDATE:**: In response this comment by OP

> `1- adding a new line of filters do i need to change the [NC] ? and 2- if i wanted to add a single word by itself do i still use RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^word [NC]? with the ^`

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} B2|Bac|Bad|Bag|Bai|Bast|Batch|Bing|Bite|Bla|Blex [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} foo|bar|etc [NC]
RewriteRule  !^spam/ http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: I had the impression that he wants to perform some kind of redirection :-?

Comment: Oh probably I got confused then.

Comment: @anubhava,sorry the question was edited to better show what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

The [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) can filter by server variables, including environment variables like your `bad_bot`. Syntax is:

> `%{ENV:variable}`, where variable can be any environment variable, is
>   also available. This is looked-up via internal Apache httpd structures
>   and (if not found there) via getenv() from the Apache httpd server
>   process.

But it can also filter by HTTP headers as well so you don't need your env variable:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Mozilla
RewriteRule  ^/$                 /homepage.max.html  [L]

RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^Lynx
RewriteRule  ^/$                 /homepage.min.html  [L]

RewriteRule  ^/$                 /homepage.std.html  [L]
```

Comment: thanks for reply, im currently using multiple wildcards using the format mentioned, for me it would be easier if there was something i can use with the format mentioned for redirection without having to recode everything.

Comment: There *is* something: `RewriteCond %{ENV:bad_bot} ...`.

Comment: Ive edited the question with better information of what im looking for. when i try to use your example it does not work, but does work using the `Deny from env=bad_bot` but only serves the 403 page.i want to redirect them to `http://officeofstrategicinfluence.com/spam/` instead

Comment: I don't think the RewriteCond directive is broken. There's probably an issue with your usage. (BTW, search engines like Bing can hardly be considered spam, esp. since you can opt-out with a simple standard [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file.)